# Testing AngularJS + Jasmine Unexpected request

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I created an application using AngularJS which you can only access after logging in.
Now I'm starting to learn how to use Jasmine.

I created a simple test (see below) just to see if everything is ok.

```
describe('dashboardController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('mainModule'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('demo', function() {
    it('demo spec', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('dashboardController', { $scope: $scope });
      expect($scope.foo).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
});
```

When I load the application I get "finished in 0.011s1 spec, 0 failures" which means the test went just fine. 
However it is blocking me from doing anything. I cant click on the login button or anything else. I also get this error in the console:
"Error: Unexpected request: GET api/getUser
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1232)"

this route above is responsible for checking if the user is logged in or not.

Im new to Jasmine with AngularJS. Can someone clarify what's going on here?

EDIT: Here's my controller:

```
angular.module("mainModule")
    .controller("dashboardController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.foo = 1;

            }]);
```

Comment: are you making any `api/getUser` request inside controller ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek not exactly inside the controller. the controller has a factory injected which has a series of requests.

Comment: @ShashankVivek I even get this error:

Error: Unexpected request: GET views/home.html
No more request expected

Comment: I just removed all the injections with any requests but still get the same error

Comment: Can you share your code of controller, not business logic but skeleton. For `views/home.html` , check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337707/error-unexpected-request-get-views-partials-for-a-nested-directive-even-when

Comment: @ShashankVivek i just edited my post. you can check the controller. with the exact same controller i get exactly the same errors